# Hibernate enableFetchProfile -> unknow

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

I want to use a FetchProfile with my DAO for the entity Example.

This is the annotation on my entity:

```
@FetchProfiles({ @FetchProfile(name = "example-profile", fetchOverrides = {
    @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = Example.class, association = "association1", mode = FetchMode.JOIN),
    @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = Example.class, association = "association2", mode = FetchMode.JOIN) }) 
})
```

This is my DAO:

```
    @Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Example getExample(Long id) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().enableFetchProfile("example-profile");
    return (Example) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Example.class, id);
}
```

When I call getExample, I got this exception:

> org.hibernate.UnknownProfileException: Unknow fetch profile [example-profile]

Am I missing mapping or something?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your entity with such **@FetchProfiles** is loaded by `SessionFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Revised

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Example getExample(Long id) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.enableFetchProfile("example-profile");

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().enableFetchProfile("example-profile");
    return (Example) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Example.class, id);
}
```